# What is the difference between (int) and intval()?

Tags: php

What is the difference between :

```
(int) '1';
```

And :

```
intval('1');
```

?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`intval()` accepts a [second argument](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) (`$base`) while `(int)` doesn't.

```
int intval( mixed $var  [, int $base = 10  ] )
```

But as long as you call `intval()` with just 1 argument (like in your case), there's no difference.

Comment: also, because intval is a function you can use it as a parameter of other functions (like array_map)

Answer (score 2):

intval have optional second parameter - base for the conversion ( default is 10).
In your case there is no difference.